# Asp.net MVC Site.master and Razor Switch

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, master-pages

I recently converted a project to visual studio 2010 then to mvc 3 and now converting views to razor views.

It's all working fine but I notice i cannot get rid of the site.master and replace it with _layout....

Every time, i start the website the default page is always rendered by site.master even tho I see it calling a controller that uses a view that uses the _layout.cshtml

I am wondering if there is at any point anywhere in the file that says the default MasterPage is the site.master ?

Comment: Do each of your individual ASPX files still reference site.master?

Comment: no aspx files are being called. but I got some aspx files that werent converted but arent being used yet.

Comment: Sometimes the easiest path is doing a *solution-wide* search *in all files types* for a string; in your case "site.master" - look wherever you are referencing it and make sure it is correct.

Comment: @KTF, I wouldn't be asking if I haven't done that much.

Comment: @Reza M.: You'd be surprised. I didn't think to ask about _ViewStart.cshtml. I thought that would have been a given. ;)

Comment: @KTF, yeah I hear you, a lot of times I forget all the simple steps. especially on the long hours after midnight :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `_ViewStart.cshtml` is pointing to the right masterpage.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
}
```

Beyond that, if `site.master` is not found in ANY of your code (solution wide search). Try restarting your application.

Comment: Rofl, can't believe i missed that. :P not obvious to remember when it auto generates for you when you create a new razor project. Thanks.